# Json handling in Smarty Issue with string conversion

Tags: php, json, smarty

I have following Value saved as json_encode in DB.

```
[{"file_name":"banner.png","file_db_id":"86f98f62-fa4a-31b6-5f53-5a4dba828e8d","file_tag":"Nails"},{"file_name":"Safari.png","file_db_id":"9eb100df-dde7-e141-146f-5a4dba35b83c","file_tag":"Spa"}]
```

When i get the value in Smarty i have the value as a text. I have tried to access the values as below but it does not print anything.

```
{foreach from=$valueJSON item=fileValues key=FileIndex}
  {assign var=fileItem value=$fileValues|json_decode:1}
       {$fileItem->file_name} 
{/foreach}
```

Just providing `{$valueJSON}` value in TPL gives the exact JSON stream as above. 
How can i loop through the values or change this `$valueJSON` to proper json object to access values.

EDIT: 
 Below code prints nothing

`{foreach from=$valueJSON item=fileValues} 
   {$fileValues|json_decode:1} 
  {/foreach}`

while if i remove the json_decode:1, it shows the value [{"file_name":"banner.png".....

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be enough to apply the `json_decode:1` to the $valueJSON in the foreach?

`{foreach from=$valueJSON|json_decode:1 item=fileValues key=FileIndex}
   ...`

I this case you don't need the json_decode in the assign.

Comment: I did tried that before, and it does not even enter the loop with that statement. 
Below code prints nothing while if i remove the json_decode:1, it shows the value [{"file_name":"banner.png".....


`{foreach from=$valueJSON item=fileValues}
{$fileValues|json_decode:1} 
{/foreach}`